# Text measure in Power BI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

Let's assume a simple table such as:

```
Category|YTD
--------+---
Cat1     |10
Cat2     |20
Cat3     | 5
```

I have been asked to create a descriptive text box such as "Cat2 is the most common category, making up 57% of the total".

As far as I can tell text boxes can only contain static text, so it would have to be either a measure or a mew column displayed as a card.  What would be the simplest way of creating it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion.  I've Googled a similar problem and found a solution which I could easily adapt to my problem:

```
Max Value Name = var MaxValue = CALCULATE(MAX(TestData[Amount]), all(TestData))
RETURN 
CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK(TestData[Name], TestData[Name]),
    TestData[Amount] = MaxValue
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new measure with the formula

```
MyMeasure = "This is the text I want to show."
```

You can use any valid DAX, i.e. you could combine the text with other measures

```
MyMeasure = "The total for foobar is " & [Total]
```

Add that measure to a card.

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.